# Can Python be used in automation

Tags: python

I currently do a lot of manual testing of a webpage performing a lot of regression on Telerik. I was wondering if Python can be used as an alternative.

I don't mind doing the courses but would be good to know what people's thoughts are.

Comment: Why you you think it's not possible ? What have you tried so far ? .

Answer (score 1):

Python is quite versatile, so it can also be used for automation:

- you can use framework with Python for unit testing, e.g. unittest is one example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html or pytest: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/
- you can use Python in combination with Selenium to test frontends: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html and https://robotframework.org/

However, automation is more than just writing automated tests, so you can use Python to data generation if you need such a thing, you can access a database with Python, you can do some data analysis, you can parse logs with Python. So it really depends on what exactly you need to do when you talk about automation.

I recommend trying out Python (possibly in combination with some other libraries/frameworks) on one project for a couple of days/weeks, then you can decide if it's the right tool for your needs.